# Custom validation for p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, customvalidator, selectonelistbox

I have the following element:

```
<p:selectOneListbox id="requirementsUrl"                                
                    value="#{data.selectedURL}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{data.requirementsDocuments}" />                                     
                    <f:validator validatorId="conf.ListValidator" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

inside my validator how I can check whether the size of the list requirementsDocuments is bigger than 0. data actually is a specific class generated by the framework that i am using and i cant directly access it through plain java code

Comment: why not check it from your constructor (or from your getter)

Answer (score 0):

In your validator you can access the value of the EL expression "#{data.requirementsDocuments}" via the FacesContext.

example:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        List requireDocuments = context.getApplication()
            .evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{data.requirementsDocuments}", List.class);
        if(requireDocuments.size() == 0) {
            throw new ValidatorException("List is empty!");
        }
    }
```